# Self contained asp.net-core deployed on a debian does not launch and shows no error message

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, debian

I'm trying to deploy a self-contained ASP.NET core application on a Debian machine but when I launch the executable the command just end without any message :

```
~/Documents$ ./publishdeb/appExecutable
~/Documents$
```

I've tried with sudo and with `chmod a+x -R publishdeb/` but it doesn't change anything.

If I publish a Windows 10 version and launch the .exe, the application works without any problem.

I encounter the same problem on Debian 9 and Debian 8.11.

The commands used are `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.1 -r debian-x64 -c Debug` to publish on debian 9 and `dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.1 -r debian.8-x64 -c Debug` to publish on Debian 8.11.

On the suggestion of omajid, I did a strace -f, that gave me back a huge amount of information that is way to big  to be entirely pasted here. Here are the 300 first lines in case there is something useful in it.

```
:~/Documents$ strace -f ./publishdeb/appExecutable
execve("./publishdeb/appExecutable", ["./publishdeb/appExecutable"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x129d000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f81000
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/C"..., 4096) = 44
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffca595aaa0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/tls", 0x7ffca595aaa0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/x86_64", 0x7ffca595aaa0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/netcoredeps", 0x7ffca595aaa0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=103192, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 103192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7f67000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7b5f000
mprotect(0x7fdab7b62000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7d61000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fdab7d61000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320n\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=137384, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2213008, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7942000
mprotect(0x7fdab795a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7b59000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7fdab7b59000
mmap(0x7fdab7b5b000, 13456, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7b5b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\270\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1008120, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f66000
mmap(NULL, 3188384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7637000
mprotect(0x7fdab7723000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7923000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xec000) = 0x7fdab7923000
mmap(0x7fdab792d000, 83616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab792d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200U\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1051056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3146072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7336000
mprotect(0x7fdab7436000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7635000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xff000) = 0x7fdab7635000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=90096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2185952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab7120000
mprotect(0x7fdab7136000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7335000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7fdab7335000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1738176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f65000
mmap(NULL, 3844640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab6d75000
mprotect(0x7fdab6f16000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab7116000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a1000) = 0x7fdab7116000
mmap(0x7fdab711c000, 14880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab711c000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f64000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f62000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fdab7f62740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab7116000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab7635000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdab7f61000
mprotect(0x7fdab7923000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab7b59000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab7d61000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x618000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab7f83000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fdab7f67000, 103192)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fdab7f62a10)         = 8766
set_robust_list(0x7fdab7f62a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fdab79489b0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fdab7951890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fdab7948a40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fdab7951890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
futex(0x7fdab793fb0c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fdab793fb18, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x129d000
brk(0x12be000)                          = 0x12be000
lstat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/self", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self", "8766", 4095)    = 4
lstat("/proc/8766", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/8766/exe", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/8766/exe", "/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/C"..., 4095) = 44
lstat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=106912, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=48640, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libhostfxr.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=692128, ...}) = 0
futex(0x7fdab7d620c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libhostfxr.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\341\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=692128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2787168, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab6acc000
mprotect(0x7fdab6b73000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab6d73000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa7000) = 0x7fdab6d73000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab6d73000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libcoreclr.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=10235936, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.deps.json", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=426901, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=48640, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=48640, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.runtimeconfig.dev.json", 0x7ffca595aad8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.runtimeconfig.json", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=98, ...}) = 0
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.runtimeconfig.json", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "{\r\n  \"runtimeOptions\": {\r\n    \"c"..., 8191) = 98
read(3, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.deps.json", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=426901, ...}) = 0
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.deps.json", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "{\r\n  \"runtimeTarget\": {\r\n    \"na"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\n          \"Microsoft.AspNetCore"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentica"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ile\": {\r\n          \"lib/netstand"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  \"Microsoft.Extensions.FileProv"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x12df000)                          = 0x12df000
read(3, ".1\",\r\n          \"Microsoft.Exten"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "s.WebSocketProtocol\": \"4.5.1\"\r\n "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"System.Data.SqlClient\": \"4.5.1"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "crosoft.Extensions.Identity.Core"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.S"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1300000)                          = 0x1300000
read(3, "{},\r\n          \"ref/netcoreapp2."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "     }\r\n      },\r\n      \"Pomelo."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"dependencies\": {\r\n          \"M"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  \"System.IO.FileSystem.Primitiv"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "yptography.Primitives\": \"4.3.0\","..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1321000)                          = 0x1321000
read(3, "\n          \"System.Runtime\": \"4."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "crosoft.NETCore.Targets\": \"2.0.0"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "2.1.2\",\r\n          \"Microsoft.As"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "e.DataProtection\": \"2.1.1\",\r\n   "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"2.1.1\"\r\n        },\r\n        \"r"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1342000)                          = 0x1342000
read(3, "  \"dependencies\": {\r\n          \""..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ng.Abstractions\": \"2.1.1\",\r\n    "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"Mic"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "mblyVersion\": \"2.1.1.0\",\r\n      "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "    \"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Work"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1363000)                          = 0x1363000
read(3, "ons.Configuration.FileExtensions"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "Extensions.Identity.Stores/2.1.3"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ": {\r\n          \"Microsoft.Identi"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "         \"assemblyVersion\": \"4.1"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"0.0.0.0\"\r\n          },\r\n      "..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1384000)                          = 0x1384000
read(3, "oreapp2.1/System.Net.WebSockets."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\": {\r\n            \"assemblyVersi"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "soft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost/2.1.5"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ndencies\": {\r\n          \"Microso"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "        \"runtime.native.System.D"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13a5000)                          = 0x13a5000
read(3, "     \"System.Linq.Queryable/4.0."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\"4.3.0\"\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n  "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  },\r\n        \"runtime\": {\r\n    "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "soft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.2.1."..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13c6000)                          = 0x13c6000
read(3, "ge\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": true,"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "/2.1.1\": {\r\n      \"type\": \"packa"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "7kZvWAK9wRG7emnTIia5O6R1Q==\",\r\n "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "m/uhPIiaws4m+Mv6ezGB0wIajvGCsHc/"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "/2.1.2\",\r\n      \"hashPath\": \"mic"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13e7000)                          = 0x13e7000
read(3, "osoft.extensions.hosting.2.1.1.n"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".0.nupkg.sha512\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"M"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"sha512\": \"sha512-st47PosZSHrjE"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "e\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": true,\r"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "r/3.0.0\": {\r\n      \"type\": \"pack"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x1408000)                          = 0x1408000
read(3, ".Tools/4.3.0\": {\r\n      \"type\": "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".sha512\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"System.Re"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ckage\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": tr"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "mlSerializer/4.3.0\": {\r\n      \"t"..., 8191) = 969
read(3, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("opt/coreservicing", 0x7ffca595b278) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("pkgs/runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy/2.1.5/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libhostpolicy.so", 0x7ffca595b1f8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libhostpolicy.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=712624, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libhostpolicy.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=712624, ...}) = 0
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/libhostpolicy.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3403\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=712624, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2807904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdab681e000
mprotect(0x7fdab68ca000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdab6aca000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xac000) = 0x7fdab6aca000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fdab6aca000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
lstat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=48640, ...}) = 0
brk(0x1399000)                          = 0x1399000
stat("opt/coreservicing", 0x7ffca595b0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.deps.json", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=426901, ...}) = 0
open("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.deps.json", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "{\r\n  \"runtimeTarget\": {\r\n    \"na"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\n          \"Microsoft.AspNetCore"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentica"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ile\": {\r\n          \"lib/netstand"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  \"Microsoft.Extensions.FileProv"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".1\",\r\n          \"Microsoft.Exten"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "s.WebSocketProtocol\": \"4.5.1\"\r\n "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"System.Data.SqlClient\": \"4.5.1"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "crosoft.Extensions.Identity.Core"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.S"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "{},\r\n          \"ref/netcoreapp2."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "     }\r\n      },\r\n      \"Pomelo."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"dependencies\": {\r\n          \"M"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  \"System.IO.FileSystem.Primitiv"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "yptography.Primitives\": \"4.3.0\","..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\n          \"System.Runtime\": \"4."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "crosoft.NETCore.Targets\": \"2.0.0"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "2.1.2\",\r\n          \"Microsoft.As"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "e.DataProtection\": \"2.1.1\",\r\n   "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"2.1.1\"\r\n        },\r\n        \"r"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "  \"dependencies\": {\r\n          \""..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ng.Abstractions\": \"2.1.1\",\r\n    "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"Mic"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "mblyVersion\": \"2.1.1.0\",\r\n      "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "    \"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Work"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ons.Configuration.FileExtensions"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "Extensions.Identity.Stores/2.1.3"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ": {\r\n          \"Microsoft.Identi"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "         \"assemblyVersion\": \"4.1"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"0.0.0.0\"\r\n          },\r\n      "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "oreapp2.1/System.Net.WebSockets."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\": {\r\n            \"assemblyVersi"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "soft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost/2.1.5"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ndencies\": {\r\n          \"Microso"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "        \"runtime.native.System.D"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "     \"System.Linq.Queryable/4.0."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "\"4.3.0\"\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n  "..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13ba000)                          = 0x13ba000
read(3, "  },\r\n        \"runtime\": {\r\n    "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "soft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.2.1."..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ge\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": true,"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "/2.1.1\": {\r\n      \"type\": \"packa"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "7kZvWAK9wRG7emnTIia5O6R1Q==\",\r\n "..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13db000)                          = 0x13db000
read(3, "m/uhPIiaws4m+Mv6ezGB0wIajvGCsHc/"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "/2.1.2\",\r\n      \"hashPath\": \"mic"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "osoft.extensions.hosting.2.1.1.n"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".0.nupkg.sha512\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"M"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, " \"sha512\": \"sha512-st47PosZSHrjE"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x13fc000)                          = 0x13fc000
read(3, "e\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": true,\r"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "r/3.0.0\": {\r\n      \"type\": \"pack"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".Tools/4.3.0\": {\r\n      \"type\": "..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, ".sha512\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"System.Re"..., 8191) = 8191
read(3, "ckage\",\r\n      \"serviceable\": tr"..., 8191) = 8191
brk(0x141d000)                          = 0x141d000
read(3, "mlSerializer/4.3.0\": {\r\n      \"t"..., 8191) = 969
read(3, "", 8191)                       = 0
brk(0x1445000)                          = 0x1445000
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/appExecutable.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=48640, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=184968, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=54264, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=29176, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=49536, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=37880, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=28032, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=29568, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=38272, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=26496, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=43904, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=91008, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=46464, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=46464, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=63872, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=21888, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=41344, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/dev/Documents/publishdeb/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=34176, ...}) = 0
```

Comment: Can you try an `strace`? What does `strace -f ./publishdeb/appExecutable` say?

Comment: Also, how did you publish the application? What was the exact `dotnet publish` command?

Comment: @omajid I added the information you asked, but the strace was way too big (370000 characters) to be pasted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did not come from either Debian or .NetCore 2.1, but from my code.

In the initialization steps of my program, I fetch the `appsettings.json` file to fill the `ConfigurationBuilder` :

```
var baseConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
```

But the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` give the directory from which the program was launched, not the directory where the assembly is. So it couldn't find the `appsettings.json` file and crashed silently.

The absence of either message or log was caused by the fact that at this step, the serilog logger was not yet initialized and couldn't send anything. `Console.WriteLine` worked, so I should have done that first.

To avoid the problem, I used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.